# Send score over to a text in another scene in unity

Tags: c#

I want to have a text in another scene saying the score at the end of the game.

```cs
public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int scoreValue = 0;
    public Text score;


    void Start()
    {
        score = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        score.text = "$ " + scoreValue;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call DontDestroyonLoad for your gameobject holding the score script before changing Scenes. Alternatively you can use Static variable for scores. But remember too always set and reset them when needed. Hope it helps :-D. Ps call you static variable on the show class like this : var tmpscore = score.scoreValue;. Showtext and after that reset your static variable on restart level.